# show previous data when switching between content pages

Tags: asp.net, telerik, master-pages

I have a site with a master page and a number of content pages.  I do a search for data in one page and then in another. Often the selected result from the first page should populate some of the search criteria in another.  How can I switch back to the previous page and retain the search results?

I have the site working when the user controls are all applied to the one default.aspx page, but the page is just getting too big.

I use a Telerik RadTab with RadPageview in the single page and an asp ContentPlaceHolder in the master/content page.

Comment: is your search in different page? or just in another tab? if its in a different page, is it necessary to be in a separate content page?

Comment: the search criteria is at the top of each content page with appropriate items for that page. The results grid/s are below so the user can always see their criteria when viewing the results.  There is a search button on each page. There are 5 related pages each associated with the Telerik tab control.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. Having everything on one page means the search is remembered but your performance suffers. You want to change it to separate pages but still retain the search.

I've written a Navigation framework that will help you, http://navigation.codeplex.com/

In the documentation I build a sample web project that has a search page with a Hyperlink from each search result going to a details page. Then there is a link on the details page that goes back to the search page and retains all the searching (and paging) information and restores the search results exactly as before.

Let me know if you're interested and want any help with it.

Comment: This is a very interesting project and I commend you for the work you've done. After a read of your PDF and running the sample code, I'm not sure how I can make it fit my scenario.  I see that your code requeries the data when navigating back to the first page.  I understand that you retain the positioning within the data which makes the page look to the user as though it hasn't changed.  However, my use of the Telerik tab control and Telerik grids will add some confusion.

Comment: My page isn't a wizard going from page 1 to 2 to 3.  It's more like allowing a user to "swim around" in a database.  For example they can search customers and click on a customer.  When they do that the code is inserted in the search criteria for assignments, billing and payroll for searching on those pages along with other appropriate criteria.  They can come back and select another customer.  If they search assignments and click on a single result, that assignment code will be placed in the billing and payroll criteria.  Some search results have multiple Telerik grids.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you like my project. It sounds to me like you should use Session to store the search criteria across pages and then recreate the search results from this criteria when they revisit a page. You can build up/change this search criteria as they select different results. That way the Session storage is kept small.

Comment: I wouldn't use Session state to store data about a page.  Two reasons here: 1. the user needs to see the search criteria for each search.  2. if the user right clicks a link and opens a new tab/window then the session state applies to both and consfuses the user.

Comment: I totally agree with you about your second point. One of the strengths of my Navigation framework is that nothing is stored in Session so you can have as many tabs/windows open as you want. You could use my framework to build a Single Page Application instead of a wizard. This would mean you're back to one page, but because you only show one 'sub page' at a time it never gets too big. I've written up an example at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301683/Knockout-Navigation-for-ASP-NET-Web-Forms